# Getting "NTLDR is missing" and can't boot into Windows XP CD because it gives BSOD 0x07B

Tags: windows, windows-xp, bsod

If I try to boot normally into hard drive with my Windows XP - I get "NTLDR is missing".
If I try to boot into Windows XP installation CD - I get BSOD 0x07B. So, basically I can't access recovery console. Correction: I get BSOD right after Windows XP **installation** CD finishes loading all of its stuff and says "Starting Windows..."

I can boot into Windows 7 installation disk, and I did try bootrec and bootsect commands in recovery console, but "NTLDR is missing" still persists.

I also switched hard drives but it didn't help with the BSOD message when booting into Win XP installation CD.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This code is normally associated to a hardware or driver failure. Have you recently changed anything in your PC configuration?

Check [this page](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000007b.htm) for more info about isolating that error.

Comment: No. Since changing harddrives didn't help is it safe to assume it's hardware failure that isn't related to the harddrive but to something else?

Comment: I suppose so. Maybe you can try testing memory, and if necessary, removing additional cards, to try to isolate the problem. I will edit my answer to suggest a link...

Comment: I tried taking out RAM one by one but it didn't solve the problem. Ran a diagnostic and it says everything Passed. I'll try to install Windows 7 instead maybe. Also tried different DVD ROM. Didn't fix. Will report back.

Answer (score 0):

I normally see that stop code 7B when a user has switched the BIOS from IDE to AHCI (or sometimes vice a versa) mode without having the correct drivers installed.

**The odds of the XP CD having AHCI drivers is slim to none.**

You can change back in the BIOS to IDE mode from AHCI or better yet do the following.

You either need to copy the AHCI drivers on to a floppy and press F8 at the right time or pre-intergrate the drivers.

[nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/download.html)

```
 Go to link download and install.
 Let it copy your windows CD onto the hard drive and then use the software to integrate the AHCI and any other drivers you want.
   Tell it to make a new ISO.
 Burn new ISO to CD/DVD
```

It should now work.  Note integrate too many drivers and it won't fit on a CD.